# Right parentheses in flex with help of keyboard event

Tags: apache-flex

I am using a text box and i added an event listener on key down.I want to know the last typed character  with the help of charCode(or any thing which is poosible).
Main problem is that when I want to press '(' i.e right parentheses then i am unable to find typed character.
All these things are in flex.So anyone??

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" applicationComplete="onComplete();">
    <mx:Script><![CDATA[
        import flash.events.TextEvent;
        private function onComplete():void
        {
            textInput.addEventListener(TextEvent.TEXT_INPUT, onTextInput);
        }
        private function onTextInput(e:TextEvent):void
        {
            var lastChar:String = e.text.charAt(e.text.length - 1);
            if (lastChar == ")")
                typed.text = "Right parentheses!!!";
            else
                typed.text = lastChar;
        }
    ]]></mx:Script>
    <mx:TextInput id="textInput"></mx:TextInput>
    <mx:Label id="typed"></mx:Label>
</mx:Application>
```